# What does "factors found" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality-in-context

The sentence is:

> Some of the **factors found** in this study were almost notorious before for being creators of unfavorable landscape or evokers of fear in human mentality.

I can't figure the "factors found" part out. Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It looks like an example of what's called *whiz-deletion*.  Imagine that it says "Some of the factors **which were** found in this study..."  Does that help you understand it?

Comment: It's my desired answer. Please write it in the answer panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some of the factors found in this study were...

is an example of something called *whiz-deletion*.  The fuller version of the sentence would be

> Some of the factors **which were** found in this study were...

but in English, we often leave out *which is* or *who is* before a participle like *called*.